# Auto scrolling using touchpad in Swift AppKit on MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

For a `NSScrollView` in Swift AppKit for MacOS, I want to be able to scroll through the list while dragging an object (e.g. file). It works using a mouse using the scroll wheel. With touch pad, it won't. My assumption is that if I move to the top of  the list, scrolling upwards starts. This works using a `ScrollView` in SwiftUI out-of-the-box.

Current code (main part):

```swift
let scrollView = NSScrollView(frame: frame)
scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = false
scrollView.autohidesScrollers = true
scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
scrollView.scrollerStyle = .overlay
        
let contentView = ContextMenuView(directoryURL: directoryURL, windowWidth: windowWidth)
scrollView.documentView = contentView
        
self.contentView = scrollView
```

Searching Google, I found some info about `NSClipView` but couldn't make this work at all.

***Actual Question:***
How can I enable (auto)scrolling when dragging a file to the top/bottom of a `NSScrollView` in AppKit on MacOS?